# Connect Sag with Cloudant in Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, cloudant, sag

How do I connect to [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) using [Sag](http://www.saggingcouch.com/) in my [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Configure Cloudant (create DB, API keys, etc.).
2. Add the following configuration to `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`:

   ```
   cloudant_hostname:    ~
   cloudant_port:        443
   cloudant_use_ssl:     true

   cloudant_database:    ~
   cloudant_username:    ~
   cloudant_password:    ~
   ```

   - If preferred, you can specify default values instead of "`~`".
3. Install sag:

   ```
   > composer.phar require "sag/sag":"dev-master"
   ```

   - At the end of this step, Composer will prompt you to enter values for the parameters listed above.
4. Define the service in your bundle's `services.yml` file:

   ```
   services:
     cloudant:
       class:  Sag
       arguments:
           - "%cloudant_hostname%"
           - "%cloudant_port%"
       calls:
           - [useSSL, ["%cloudant_use_ssl%"]]
           - [setDatabase, ["%cloudant_database%"]]
           - [login, ["%cloudant_username%", "%cloudant_password%"]]
   ```
5. Access the service in your controller:

   ```
   /** @var \Sag $sag */
   $sag = $this->get('cloudant');

   /* You're now good to go! */
   $post = $sag->get('postID')->body;
   ```